# How to get neigbor pixel coordinates in Unity HLSL shader

Tags: unity, shaders, hlsl, image-effects

I am writing Mandelbrot set shader for Unity.

I wrote an Image Effect shader and it works.

Unfortunately, each point "shimmers" on translate scale. This is because, for each shader call I compute value for only one mathematical point, which is infinitesimal. On even small translation, the value can change drastically.

So, I would like to compute math value not for one point, but for several. But for this I need to know, which aother points belong to my pixel, and for this I need to know the distance to neighbor pixel. Unfortunately, my incoming values are float and I don't know, how to step to next pixel.

How to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your shader you'll have a declaration of your texture sampler, something like this:

```
sampler2D _MainTex; // This is the sampler.
float4 _MainTex_ST; // This is the scale/offset parameters set in the material widget.
```

Add one extra line below these:

```
float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;
```

This gives you a variable you can access in your shader, that [Unity will pre-populate as described in the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/SL-PropertiesInPrograms.html):

> **Texture size**
> {TextureName}_TexelSize - a float4 property contains texture size information:
>
> - x contains 1.0/width
> - y contains 1.0/height
> - z contains width
> - w contains height

Now you can use this in your shader. Where the "current" pixel being drawn is...

```
float2 thisPixel = i.uv;
```

We can shift this to get...

```
float2 rightNeighbour  = i.uv + float2(_MainTex_TexelSize.x, 0);
float2 leftNeighbour   = i.uv - float2(_MainTex_TexelSize.x, 0);
float2 topNeighbour    = i.uv + float2(0, _MainTex_TexelSize.y);
float2 bottomNeighbour = i.uv - float2(0, _MainTex_TexelSize.y);
```

And of course you can scale this by a scalar to reach over only half a pixel, or two pixels, or combine both x & y to access a neighbouring point in any diagonal direction.

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't work by some reason, don't understand why yet

Comment: What symptoms are you observing? How are you using this shader at present? The more information you can share, the better we can help you solve the problem.

Comment: Image started to duplicate with several "ghosts", as if docs about `width` and `height` is either incorrect or incomplete. Probably `width` and `height` are just 100 or something. Unfortunately, I don't know how to display the values from within shader.

Comment: The docs are correct, but the way you're using them might be incorrect. Try editing your question to walk us through all the steps needed to reproduce this problem in a new empty project.

Comment: Sure. Why is it saying about "texture" width and height? I have no texture at all.

Comment: Are you reading the output of a frame buffer to apply post-processing or blitting effects to it? Your rendered frame is a texture in that case. If not, then you should definitely explain in your question in more detail/sample code what exactly you're doing, so that we can tailor answers to suit.

Comment: I am using this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kY7liQVPQSc